# slow network in centos5 VM with centos5 host running KVM

Tags: linux, networking, centos, kvm-virtualization

I setup KVM following the guide here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-linux-kvm-virtulization-tutorial/

I setup a bridged network and it worked fine except that the transfer speed is 200KB/s instead of the gigabit speed that I get on the host machine by itself.

I tried editing the guest network settings to set "model=virtio"

http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Virtio

but this just moves ifconfig-eth0 to ifconfig-eth0.bak in the VM and networking doesn't work at all.  I tried moving ifconfig-eth0 back and starting up eth0, which works, but now the transfer speed is ~ 60KB/s

I have no idea what else to try.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 200 KB/s is very poor, which CentOS and KVM version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must configure iptables to allow all traffic to be forwarded across the bridge:

```
$ sudo iptables -I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
$ sudo service iptables save
$ sudo service iptables restart
```

and prevent bridged traffic from being processed by iptables rules, **this improves the bridge’s performance**. In /etc/sysctl.conf append the following lines:

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

then reload the kernel parameters configured with sysctl:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and restart the libvirt daemon.

```
$ sudo service libvirtd reload
```

you can find more here [Bridged networking with libvirt](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Network_Configuration-Bridged_networking_with_libvirt.html) and I describe here the full process of [How to install KVM and libvirt on CentOS 6.2 with bridged networking](http://eduardo-lago.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-install-kvm-and-libvirt-on.html)

Answer (score 0):

virtio will typically get you the best performance, but some hardware doesn't work well with it -- try switching model to e1000 (assuming a gigabit NIC from what you've said) and see if it works better.

**EDIT:** What does your bridging configuration on the host look like?  I'm familiar with doing this on the Debian/Ubuntu side of things rather than RH/CentOS, but a typical /etc/network/interfaces setup for us would look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
```

Also, are your guests fully virtualized (can ensure with --hvm switch in libvirt)?

Lastly, if you have a different NIC kicking around that you can install to experiment with you might install it to see if it makes a difference.  If not, you might want to pick one up -- we've had good luck with the relatively cheap Intel desktop gigabit NICs.

Comment: e1000 runs at the same speed as virtio.  are there any other model numbers i can try?

Comment: just tried rstl8139 also.  same low network speed.

Comment: See additions to answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Using virtio will provide the better speeds. Which version are you running exactly?